# AVG returning null but should not

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I have a *Birthdate* field with theses values:

```
28 Juillet 1982   (I want this one to be excluded)
09/16/1981        (This one will be used)
                  (empty, should be excluded)
03/19/1953        (This one will be used)
```

I want to get the average age of the mm/dd/yyyy dates. Right now my query is:

```
SELECT AVG(NULLIF(YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(Birthdate), 0)) AS AvgAge FROM `User`
```

I also tried:

```
SELECT AVG( YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(Birthdate) ) AS AvgAge FROM `User`
```

But the result is always the same: *NULL*

Every id_user that are 100% numerics have a correct mm/dd/yyyy birthdate, so I also tried that:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN id_user >=0 THEN YEAR( NOW( ) ) - YEAR( Birthdate ) ELSE NULL END )  AS AvgAge FROM `User`
```

And that:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN CEIL(id_user) = id_user THEN YEAR( NOW( ) ) - YEAR( Birthdate ) ELSE NULL END )  AS AvgAge FROM `User`
```

Still *NULL*...

Do you have any idea why it does that?
Maybe a simple error of mine but I can't figure it out.

Thanks !

Comment: Is it varchar or datetime type for that column?

Comment: That might be your problem - does the YEAR function know what to do with a varchar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-types.html

I think the type might not be right.

> Although MySQL tries to interpret values in several formats, date
>   parts must always be given in year-month-day order (for example,
>   '98-09-04'), rather than in the month-day-year or day-month-year
>   orders commonly used elsewhere (for example, '09-04-98', '04-09-98').

Comment: Thanks that was the problem! I finally took the year from Birthdate by using SUBSTRING(Birthdate, -4) !!

Answer (score 1):

you wrote it wrong,  you use `nulllif` instead of `IFNULL` try this:

```
SELECT AVG(IFNULL(YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(Birthdate), 0)) AS AvgAge FROM `User`
```

Answer (score 0):

As duffymo said, because the type of the Birthdate column is VACHAR, YEAR() can't work.

So I finally did:

```
SELECT AVG(IF(CONCAT('',id_user*1) = id_user, (YEAR(NOW()) - SUBSTRING(Birthdate, -4)), NULL))  AS nbUserWithCorrectDate FROM `User`
```